# Place a single scrollbar for the frames that are displayed in a single window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

There are two frames that have to be displayed in a single window. The second exceeds the display size and **the scrollbar has to placed for the entire window.**

```
from tkinter import *

rectangle_values = []
k = 0

def open_window(rectangles):
    global k
    window.title('Rectangles')
    print(rectangles)
    for i in range(0, int(rectangles) * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(frame2, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        en = Entry(frame2)
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)

    frame2.tkraise()

    b4 = Button(frame2, text="Back", width=12, command=lambda: (frame1.tkraise(), window.title('Rectangle Configuration')))
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles) * 2 + 1, column=1)
    k = int(rectangles)

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=220,height=700)
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")   


window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x800')
frame1 = Frame(window)
frame1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
frame2 = Frame(window)
frame2.grid(row = 10, column = 0)
frame1.tkraise()

l3 = Label(frame1, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0, column=0)

# defining entries
rectangles = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Defining buttons
b1 = Button(frame1, text='Submit', width=12, command=lambda: open_window(rectangles.get()))
b1.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

So, this is code here. When the number of rectangle is more than 18, we need a scrollbar.

```
myframe=Frame(window)
canvas=Canvas(myframe)
frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))
myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
window.bind("<MouseWheel>", myfunction)
myframe.grid(row=3, column=7)
```

I added this but the scrollbar is between the two frames. How do I put a scrollbar that is for the entire window?

Comment: consider to accept my question if you think it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shold use another approach, try to use more the Canvas widget, do somethink like this is more easier.

```
import tkinter as tk


def open_window(rect):
    window.title('Rectangles')
    print(rect)
    x, y = 100, 50
    for i in range(0, rect * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Size of rectangle:")
            canvas.create_window(0, y, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)
        en = tk.Entry(canvas)
        canvas.create_window(x, y, window=en, anchor=tk.NW)
        y += 20
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


window = tk.Tk()
window.configure()

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 500  # width for the Tk root
h = 300  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="black", width=500, height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, command=canvas.yview)
canvas_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas_scroll.set, scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 300))

rect_var = tk.IntVar()
entry_rect_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rect_var)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=entry_rect_number, anchor=tk.NW)

sumbit_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="sumbit", command=lambda: open_window(rect_var.get()))
canvas.create_window(0, 20, window=sumbit_button, anchor=tk.NW)

# Here is the frame
canvas_frame1 = tk.Canvas(canvas, bg="red", width=150, height=290)
frame_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame1, command=canvas_frame1.yview)
frame_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
canvas_frame1.configure(yscrollcommand=frame_scroll.set, scrollregion=(0, 0, 200, 400))

canvas_frame1.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50)

canvas.create_window(250, 0, window=canvas_frame1, anchor=tk.NW)

canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))

window.mainloop()
```

I don't know if there is a way for scroll a `Frame` from the `main window` but my advice is to create a `Canvas` where you put all your `widgets` and add a `scrollbar` to the `Canvas` so that all the `widgets` inside the `Canvas` are easily scrolled.

for more infos about the `Canvas` and all its methods see [this site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: I added myframe.grid(row=y, column=x), but when I hit submit, the scrollbar disappears.

Comment: updated. and the scroll bar appeared between the two frames. How do I make it work for the entire window?

Comment: Try to do something like this

Comment: This works but I am just a beginner and this is hard for me to understand. Can you help me put scrollbar just around the second frame? Just making a certain size of frame and putting a scroll bar.

Comment: I've edited the code and a link where you can study the `Canvas` widget :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191660/discussion-between-devin-maharjan-and-mat-c).